# Parallel.ForEach apparently cloning reference type?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, parallel.foreach

I have a simple method:

```
private IEnumerable<OrderResult> SubmitOrders(IEnumerable<OrderItem> items)
{
    ConcurrentBag<OrderResult> results = new ConcurrentBag<OrderResult>();

    Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
        {
            OrderResult result = SubmitOrder(item);
            results.Add(result);
        });

    return results;
}
```

To add further context, the `SubmitOrder(item)` method referenced above changes the `Sent` (`DateTime?`) property on the `item` object to `DateTime.Now`, if the order is submitted successfully.

Inside the `Parallel.ForEach` loop, after `SubmitOrder(item)`, I can see that the `Sent` property has been updated correctly.

HOWEVER, if I examine the object in the passed in `items` parameter, then none of the `Sent` properties have been updated. It is as though the items being passed into the `Parallel.ForEach` loop aren't those in the original `items` collection.

Why is this? If the objects in the passed in collection were modified in the loop, I expected the changes to be reflected in the items in the original collection, but they don't appear to be.

Comment: And `OrderItem` is not a value type, right?

Comment: No, OrderItem is a class.  But the "Sent" property that is assigned within the loop is a Nullable<DateTime> type (struct), and I'm wondering if this is the problem.

Comment: What target framework?

Comment: There was a change in the compiler in Visual Studio 2012 that changes the way closures are handled so that some variables are copied instead of just referenced.  But, I don't see how that would affect you here because there isn't any other code (outside ForEach) that modifies items in the collection; so even if it did have a copy, it should be the same as the original.

Comment: It would make sense to me if this was a cloned/deep-copied object, but I'm not sure how to prove that that's the case.  Or, even why it should be the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter type of `items` is `IEnumerable<OrderItem>`.  If `items` hasn't been enumerated yet, and enumerating them creates new objects, then that could be the cause, as the objects you're updating in `SubmitOrder()` are not the same as the objects the next time `items` is enumerated.  Here is a full LINQPad C# program that demonstrates what I mean.

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<OrderItem> itemsAsIEnumerable =
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 5)
            .Select(i => new OrderItem() { ItemNumber = i });
    SubmitOrders(itemsAsIEnumerable);
    itemsAsIEnumerable.Dump();
        /* Displays:
        ItemNumber Sent
        1 null 
        2 null 
        3 null 
        4 null 
        5 null 
        */

    IEnumerable<OrderItem> itemsAsList =
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 5)
            .Select(i => new OrderItem() { ItemNumber = i })
            .ToList();
    SubmitOrders(itemsAsList);
    itemsAsList.Dump();
        /* Displays:
        ItemNumber Sent
        1 2/5/2014 10:01:58 AM
        2 2/5/2014 10:01:58 AM
        3 2/5/2014 10:01:58 AM
        4 2/5/2014 10:01:58 AM
        5 2/5/2014 10:01:58 AM
        */      
}

private IEnumerable<OrderResult> SubmitOrders(IEnumerable<OrderItem> items)
{
    ConcurrentBag<OrderResult> results = new ConcurrentBag<OrderResult>();

    Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
        {
            OrderResult result = SubmitOrder(item);
            results.Add(result);
        });

    return results;
}

private OrderResult SubmitOrder(OrderItem item)
{
    item.Sent = DateTime.Now;
    return new OrderResult();
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Sent { get; set; }
}

public class OrderResult
{
}
```

Comment: Good call, Ben! I think this is the problem.  I did a quick test just by calling .ToList() on the IEnumerable<OrderItem> I was passing into the method, and I got the expected behaviour.